# tinysort sort divs based on custom array order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tinysort

I'm currently using the tinysort.js plugin and I'd like to sort some divs based on an array. I'm not exactly sure how to go about this with tinysort.

This is what I currently have:

html:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="row" data-type="fruit">banana</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="fruit">apple</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="fruit">avocado</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="dairy">milk</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="other">car</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="dairy">cheese</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="grain">rice</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="grain">wheat</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="grain">barley</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var $rows = $('#list .row');
var order = ['grain', 'fruit', 'dairy']; // this is the order I'd like the divs to be in

tinysort($rows, {sortFunction:function(a, b) {
    var rowA = $(a.elm).data('type');
    var rowB = $(b.elm).data('type');

    return rowA == rowB ? 0 : (rowA > rowB ? 1 : -1);
}});
```

How can I apply the order array so the divs will be sorted accordingly?

Comment: Can order be an object instead?

Comment: If you can do it via object, I can modify what you make to work with an array.

Comment: Are you using jQuery's version of tinySort?

Comment: I'm using this: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using `Array.prototype.indexOf` will work:

```
tinysort($rows, {sortFunction:function(a, b) {
    var rowA = order.indexOf($(a.elm).data('type'));
    var rowB = order.indexOf($(b.elm).data('type'));

    return rowA == rowB ? 0 : (rowA > rowB ? 1 : -1);
}});
```

Comment: Good :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use an object instead of an array then:

```js
var $rows = $('#list .row');

var order = {   // the order is an object that maps types into an integer that represents the precedence (the lower the number the higher the precedence is)
  'grain': 0,
  'fruit': 1,
  'dairy': 2,
  'other': 3
};

tinysort($rows, {sortFunction:function(a, b) {
    var rowA = $(a.elm).data('type');
    var rowB = $(b.elm).data('type');
    
    rowA = order[rowA];  // get the integer representation of this type
    rowB = order[rowB];  // get the integer representation of this type

    return rowA == rowB ? 0 : (rowA > rowB ? 1 : -1); // if the two integers are the same (same precedence) then return 0, otherwise return either 1 or -1 depending on who's should come first using the integer representaion (I think it is self explanatory ;))
}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinysort/2.3.6/tinysort.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
    <div class="row" data-type="fruit">banana</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="fruit">apple</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="fruit">avocado</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="dairy">milk</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="other">car</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="dairy">cheese</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="grain">rice</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="grain">wheat</div>
    <div class="row" data-type="grain">barley</div>
</div>
```

**Note** that if you still want the array, then it could easily be transformed into an equivalent object:

```
var orderObject = orderArray.reduce((obj, t, i) => (obj[t] = i, obj), {});
```

**Note** that all types should be included, otherwise the sort will be broken as the integer representaion won't exist, thus `undefined` and `number < undefined` and `undefined < number` are always `false`. You can do a test to check if it's `undefined` inside the sort function if you don't want to include all types in the `order` variable.